# Matlab,alphabetic order of the intersect result

Tags: string, matlab, cell, intersect

I use **intersect function** to find common strings in two cell arrays A and B ([~,idx]=intersect(A,B))and save indexes in **idx**. Then I extract the common strings by A(idx). I see that the results are sorted in alphabetic order. I want to sort them as they sorted in A, Why these strings sorted in alphabetic order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html), you can add the option `setOrder='stable'` to preserve the order of the elements:

```
[C,ia,ib] = intersect(A,B,'stable');
```

You don't even have to capture the indices (unless used elsewhere), as the example shows:

> `C = intersect([7 0 5],[7 1 5],'stable')`
>   returns
>   `C = [7 5]`

and

```
A='hgfedcba';
B='hac';
[~,ia]=intersect(A,B,'stable');
ia'

>   1   6   8

A(ia)

>   hca
```

### For Matlab R2011b and older:

If your matlab version doesn't support the `'stable'` option, you can just use `sort` on the indices:

```
[~,ia]=intersect(A,B);
ia=sort(ia);
A(ia)

>   1   6   8

A(sort(ia))
```

### Duplicates

If they're duplicates in `A`, intersect will only find them once. [ismember](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) might be better suited if you want to find all of the duplicates:

```
A='hhggffeeddccbbaa';
B='hac';
[~,ia]=intersect(A,B);
ia=sort(ia);
A(ia)

>   hca

[~,loc] = ismember(A,B);
ia=find(loc~=0); % because you want the indices (logical indexing is also an option of course)
A(ia)

>   hhccaa
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any method to save only index of strings? I use [~,idx]=intersect(A,b,'stable') but it does not work.Any other idea for intersect? I use find(ismember(A,B)) it works with not alphabetic order and by index order. how about intersect?

Comment: Thanks for edition but it doesn't work.??? Error using ==> intersect at 165 Unknown flag.

Comment: you're obviously doing something different than in my answer. I don't have my crystal ball with me, so it's up to you to better describe what you're doing and what goes wrong. There's more room too post in your question than in the comments btw

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments and answer. I just test your example for[~,ia]=intersect(A,B,'stable') and I copy and paste your example. I use Matlab version R2011a.I think you understand me very well but the code doesn't work.